# React Native Integration with Existing App

Tags: ios, react-native

I want to integration with existing App.

In the ReactNative docs :

```
Remember to install all subspecs you need. The <Text> element cannot be used without pod 'React/RCTText'.
```

Now, there are something wrong in the simulator:

```
Cant't find variable:ListView
```

I want to use `<ListView>` and what subspecs I will install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView can be used when you pod 'React', I think there may be something wrong with your javascript code. Have you included these code in your js file ?

```js
var {
  ListView,
} = React;
```